# Append output of a command to file without newline

Tags: unix, append, printf, output

I have the following line in a unix script:

```
head -1 $line | cut -c22-29  >> $file
```

I want to append this output with no newline, but rather separated with commas.  Is there any way to feed the output of this command to printf? I have tried:

```
head -1 $line | cut -c22-29 | printf "%s, " >> $file
```

I have also tried:

```
printf "%s, " head -1 $line | cut -c22-29 >> $file
```

Neither of those has worked.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just want tr in your case

```
tr '\n' ','
```

will replace all the newlines ('\n') with commas

```
head -1 $line | cut -c22-29 | tr '\n' ',' >> $file
```

Answer (score 0):

An very old topic, but even now i have been needed to do this (on limited command resources) and that one (replied) command havent been working for me due to its length.

Appending to a file can be done also by using file-descriptors:

- `touch file.txt` (create new blank file),
- `exec 100<> file.txt` (new fd with id 100),
- `echo -n test >&100` (echo test to new fd)
- `exec 100>&-` (close new fd)

Appending starting from specyfic character can be done by reading file from certain point eg.

- `exec 100 <> file.txt` - new descriptor
- `read -n 4 < &100` - read 4 characters
- `echo -n test > &100` - append echo test to a file starting from forth character.
- `exec 100>&-` - (close new fd)